# What is the difference between RabbitMQ exclusive queue vs. exclusive consumer?

Tags: rabbitmq

Having trouble wrapping my ahead around the differences between `exclusive queue` and `exclusive consumer`, and was wondering if I had this correct.

Let's say I have a `queue`, `consumer1`, and `consumer2`.

My understanding is:

**exclusive queue**

If `queue` is `exclusive queue` and was created by `consumer1`, only `consumer1` can access the queue, and when `consumer1` goes down, `queue` is deleted. It sounds like messages are then lost.

**exclusive consumer**

If `queue` is NOT exclusive and was created by `consumer1`, then both `consumer1` and `consumer2` can read from it. If `consumer1` goes down, `consumer2` can pick up where it left off. If `consumer1` is `exclusive consumer` and starts a subscription first, then `consumer2` cannot access `queue`, while it is locked by `consumer1`.

`exclusive queue` sounds like a weird use case to me whereas `exclusive consumer` sounds like the proper solution for "only 1 consumer should process from the queue at a time".

Answer (score 4):

I think the difference between them is that for `exclusive` queue it can only be consumed by `consumers` that are on the same connection which is used for declaring the queue.  When this connection is closed or disconnected, the `exclusive` queue is automatically closed by `rabbitmq`. The use case for it is that you usually want the queue to be destroyed when the `exclusive` (private) consumer exit or disconnect.

Whereas the use case for `exclusive` consumer on a normal `queue` is slightly different. The private consumer may be gone or disconnected but another consumer can be the successor of the next `exclusive` consumer, and it may not have to be on the same `rabbitmq` connection as the one used for declaring the `queue`.

Essentially both use cases are about allowing `exclusive` access to the queue but the latter is less strict.

Comment: To expand a bit on this excellent answer, if there is an ordinary message queue and consumer A decides it wants to **exclusively** consume from it, it is allowed to and all messages are delivered to A. Afterwards, consumer B will **not** be allowed to listen to this queue. If A either drops off, loses connection, or cancels the (connection) channel, then it is application's responsibility to either restart the A, or create another consumer. The queue with messages in it stays there though.